# how to make a JSP include a JSPF with EL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, facelets, jsp-tags

How do I include a JSP fragment in another JSP **using** [EL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language) **specifically**?

login.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="${sessionScope.auth.duke}"> 
        my name is ${requestScope.controller.myName}, ${requestScope.controller.myId}, what's yours?
        <form name="user_name_form" action="controller" method="POST">
            login: <input type="text" name="login" value="" size='20' />
            <p>
                <input type="submit">
            </p>
        </form>
        ${sessionScope.auth.greeting}
        <p/>
        fragment goes here with EL...
        <p/>
</body>
</html>
```

fragment.jspf:

```
<%-- any content can be specified here e.g.: --%>
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>

fragment here
```

Or, is it not possible to include the fragment with [EL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language)?

I'm aware of many examples utilizing the JSTL.  It's not impossible that I'm misunderstanding the interplay of these technologies.

> The expression language started out as part of the JavaServer Pages
>   Standard Tag Library (JSTL) and was originally called SPEL (Simplest
>   Possible Expression Language), then just Expression Language (EL). It
>   was a scripting language which allowed access to Java components
>   (JavaBeans) through JSP. Since JSP 2.0, it has been used inside JSP
>   tags to separate Java code from JSP, and to allow easier access to
>   Java components (than in Java code).

--[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language)

and:

> Since JSP 2.0, standard EL was moved from JSTL to JSP and maintained
>   as part of the JSP specification.

--[SO wiki entry on EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

see also:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/434381/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/jspf-working-jsp-include-jsp

Answer (score 0):

If the EL in your fragment isn't getting evaluated, then that's probably because your app server doesn't know that it needs to evaluate the EL. As you can see in that linked post, if you are on Tomcat, the solution is simply to add some lines to your web.xml file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you aren't on Tomcat, then you'll have to figure out what configuration you need to specify in order to tell your app server to run the JSP servlet on files with the .jspf extension.